# How to obtain a dataframe of trees from a CatBoost model similar to XGBoost's model.get_booster().trees_to_dataframe()

Tags: python, xgboost, catboost, boosting

I'm working with CatBoost and I need to extract information about the trees generated by a trained CatBoost model in the form of a dataframe, similar to how it can be done with XGBoost using model.get_booster().trees_to_dataframe(). This information is helpful for further analysis and visualization.

Is there an equivalent method or approach in CatBoost to achieve this? If so, could you please provide a code example or guidance on how to obtain a dataframe of the trees from a CatBoost model?

Possibly these values should be there in the DataFrame or any other object with required information
`Tree   Node    ID  Feature Split   Yes No  Missing Gain    Cover`

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor

model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=20, n_jobs=10,
                        objective='reg:squarederror')


model.fit(X[0]['train'], Y['train'])
trees = model.get_booster().trees_to_dataframe()
```

[image]

I want to get a similar DF with all details in catboost:

```
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor

model = CatBoostRegressor( iterations=10,
                            thread_count=10)
                        

model.fit(X['train'], Y['train'], cat_features=range(n_num_features, n_features))
```

Comment: Not a dataframe, but maybe [plot_tree](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboost_plot_tree) would help you visualize it?

Comment: I don't want to visualize it, instead get values for leaves and decision boundaries at each node. I have tried (plot_tree), but that's just a graphic rather than values for each component.